# How to add maven dependency

Tags: java, maven-2

I have a jar for jboss messaging, and I don't know group id and artifact id and version, I just have a working jar , how can I add dependency

**EDIT**

I assume there is a jar somewhere online, I once found a sontype maven repository with search possability if I found it, probably the messaging jar would be there. Does anybody know the url ?

Found it :

http://maven.nuxeo.org/nexus/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of this jboss-messaging case, you can manually install any jar:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<myGroup> \
    -DartifactId=<myArtifactId> -Dversion=<myVersion> -Dpackaging=<myPackaging>
```

Then just use these values in `<dependency>` tag:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>myGroup</groupId> 
    <artifactId>myArtifactId</artifactId> 
    <version>myVersion</version>
</dependency>
```

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Answer (score 1):

In that case, use a [repository search engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887615/which-dependency-do-i-need-for-this-import-in-maven/1887947#1887947), for example:

http://mavensearch.net/search?q=jboss-messaging

I particularly like [mavensearch.net](http://mavensearch.net) because it has lots of indexed repositories, including jboss repository.

If you can find an existing repository containing the artifact you're looking for, **prefer** this solution over the manual install of an artifact in your local repository (not portable) and over using a `system` scope (worse than the manual install).

Comment: Also http://www.mvnbrowser.com/index.html is good.  And if you know a Class name but not which .jar it's in try http://www.findjar.com/index.x

Answer (score 0):

This should do you:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>jboss.messaging</groupId> 
    <artifactId>jboss-messaging</artifactId> 
    <version>1.4.6.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://repository.sonatype.org) is the real sonatype repository you mentioned. The other is just running Nexus, and has only central proxied. Check out the this one.