# how do I add apache commons logging using the maven2 with eclipse?

Tags: java, spring, maven-2, apache-commons, m2eclipse

I can't seem to find apache common logging when using eclipse w/maven2 plugin.

I need it for spring3 mvc apparently.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do you know that the m2eclipse plugin can search some indexed repositories, like *central*? For example, if you **right-click** on your project and go to **Maven > Add Dependency**, you can use it like this:

[image]

And this will add this to your pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Another option is to use one of the [numerous](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#How_to_find_dependencies) [repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887615/which-dependency-do-i-need-for-this-import-in-maven/1887947#1887947) [search engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192050/how-do-i-find-out-apache-buildr-maven-2-repo-names/2192127#2192127), for example:

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|commons-logging|commons-logging|1.1.1|jar

Comment: Yes I did know that, I just wasn't sure if that was from apache or not?  Thanks for the repo search tip!  I guess i'll add that 59K one you have highlighted.

Comment: The apache libraries often leave out apache in their name.  To their detriment i think.