# Mixed usage of Log4j and commons-logging causes a "class loading deadlock"?

Tags: java, multithreading, log4j, deadlock, apache-commons-logging

I think I found a situation where mixed usage of log4j a) directly and b) via commons-logging causes some kind of class-loading deadlock. I'm not sure if such a situation is possible at all (shouldn't the JVM detect that?) and what to do about it.

#### The problem

In our build system, we currently are running our unit tests sequentially - to make the build faster, we obviously can change that to run our unit tests in parallel. However, if we do so, some builds run into an execution timeout. When analysing the thread dump of such "hanging builds", we find ourselves in different modules with different tests involved most of the time. But it always boils down to two threads trying the initialize a Logger: one with `Logger.getLogger` (directly using log4j), the other with `LogFactory.getLog` (using commons-logging).

#### My analysis

So we have one thread (the one using log4j directly) waiting at this place:

```
"pool-1-thread-3" prio=10 tid=0x00007f6528ca6000 nid=0x6f8f in Object.wait() [0x00007f64d9ca6000]
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:82)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:117)
at de.is24.platform.contacts.domain.PhoneNumberFormat.<clinit>(PhoneNumberFormat.java:21)
```

which, unfortunately, is a rather "crowded" line:

```
Hierarchy h = new Hierarchy(new RootLogger((Level) Level.DEBUG));
```

And another thread (using commons-logging) waiting here:

```
"pool-1-thread-2" prio=10 tid=0x00007f6528bf9800 nid=0x6f8e in Object.wait() [0x00007f64d9da7000]
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at org.apache.log4j.Priority.<clinit>(Priority.java:45)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.class$(Log4JLogger.java:37)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<clinit>(Log4JLogger.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:529)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:235)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:209)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
```

which is straightforward:

```
final static public Priority FATAL = new Level(FATAL_INT, "FATAL", 0);
```

So to me, it seems like the second thread is in the process of initializing class `Priority` and waits to load the `Level` class.
The first thread probably attempts to load the `Level` class (the other stuff in that line seems unrelated), and as the `Level` class extends `Priority`, waits for the `Priority` class to be loaded.
There we have our deadlock.

So, can you tell me if this analysis is correct? Or did I miss something?

**UPDATE I**

I wrote some test cases, you can find them here: https://github.com/sebastiankirsch/classloading

There are several test cases demonstrating the problem:

1. `TestLoadingByClassForName` should cause a deadlock rather quickly (every third run on my machine)
2. `TestLoadingMixed` represents a version of the problem being stripped down to the minimum of the observed stack trace; this one fails much more infrequently (roughly by factor 4)
3. `TestMixedLoggerInstantiation` mimics the behaviour: one class instantiates a logger using log4j, another using commons-logging. The deadlock is hard to catch here, as there is much more code involved - I needed to add a random sleep which certainly needs to be adapted to your machine

Here's a stack trace of the `TestMixedLoggerInstantiation` test case hanging.

```
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.1-b02 mixed mode):

"UseLog4JLogger" prio=10 tid=0x00007fa1f017d800 nid=0x7bd8 in Object.wait() [0x00007fa1e5ba4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:82)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:117)
    at net.tcc.classloading.UseLog4JLogger.run(UseLog4JLogger.java:23)

"UseCommonsLoggingLogFactory" prio=10 tid=0x00007fa1f00e5000 nid=0x7bd7 in Object.wait() [0x00007fa1e5ca4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at org.apache.log4j.Priority.<clinit>(Priority.java:45)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.class$(Log4JLogger.java:37)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<clinit>(Log4JLogger.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:529)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:235)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:209)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
    at net.tcc.classloading.UseCommonsLoggingLogFactory.run(UseCommonsLoggingLogFactory.java:13)

"ReaderThread" prio=10 tid=0x00007fa1f00ed000 nid=0x7bd6 runnable [0x00007fa1e5da6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
    - locked <0x00000007d7088a00> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)
    - locked <0x00000007d7088a00> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner$ReaderThread.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:140)

"Low Memory Detector" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fa1f009d800 nid=0x7bd4 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fa1f009b800 nid=0x7bd3 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fa1f0098800 nid=0x7bd2 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fa1f0096800 nid=0x7bd1 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fa1f007a000 nid=0x7bd0 in Object.wait() [0x00007fa1e6c54000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007d7001300> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:118)
    - locked <0x00000007d7001300> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:134)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:159)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fa1f0078000 nid=0x7bcf in Object.wait() [0x00007fa1e6d55000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007d70011d8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:116)
    - locked <0x00000007d70011d8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=10 tid=0x00007fa1f000c000 nid=0x7bc5 in Object.wait() [0x00007fa1f50b0000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007d730dfd8> (a net.tcc.classloading.UseCommonsLoggingLogFactory)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1186)
    - locked <0x00000007d730dfd8> (a net.tcc.classloading.UseCommonsLoggingLogFactory)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1239)
    at net.tcc.classloading.TestMixedLoggerInstantiation.test(TestMixedLoggerInstantiation.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007fa1f0071800 nid=0x7bce runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fa1f001f000 nid=0x7bc6 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fa1f0021000 nid=0x7bc7 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fa1f0022800 nid=0x7bc8 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fa1f0024800 nid=0x7bc9 runnable 

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fa1f0026800 nid=0x7bca runnable 

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fa1f0028000 nid=0x7bcb runnable 

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fa1f002a000 nid=0x7bcc runnable 

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fa1f002c000 nid=0x7bcd runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007fa1f00a8800 nid=0x7bd5 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 1168
```

#### Reproducing the deadlock

Download the code from https://github.com/sebastiankirsch/classloading.
`TestLoadingByClassForName` should easily cause a deadlock for you (just run it a few times), this is a prerequisite that your system/JVM will eventually run into a deadlock for the complex scenario.

Now run `TestMixedLoggerInstantiation` several times. Note the average run time, open up `UseLog4JLogger` and set the sleep timer sum to a little less than the average run time. This will eventually cause a deadlock, but it's occurring rarely.

Therefore, run it on the command line like this:

```
for (( ; ; )) do
  testExectution
done
```

Instead of putting the `testExecution` together manually, just set a break boint in the test, debug, type `ps -ef | grep TestMixedLoggerInstantiation` in a shell, and copy the command your IDE uses.

Comment: Both your threads are in Runnable state, not Waiting or Blocked. Can you provide a complete thread dump from the time your system hangs?

Comment: I've added the stack trace to the original question.

You're right, the threads are in Runnable state, but the first lines say they are both _in Object.wait()_

Comment: Nothing suggests to me that the classloader is actually involved.  <clinit> is the class static initializer; see http://stackoverflow.com/q/8517121/1448212

Comment: Yeah, obviously the classes `Priority` and `LogManager` are in the process of being statically initialized.
But what are the threads doing for minutes (or forever if you let them) at these spots?

Do you know how the process of class loading is represented in the stack trace? I'm not sure, but the second thread shows a `Class.forName` as a result of this line in `Log4JLogger`: `private static final boolean is12 = Priority.class.isAssignableFrom(Level.class);`
So this is probably class loading...

Comment: Few questions: Which JDK version are you using? Can you tell which exact versions of the logging frameworks you have running? Any classloading specialties? Have you tried to zero in on the problem (e.g. remove all variables in a minimum testing environment, only two threads only two tests that hang etc.)?

Comment: I've added some test cases, being stripped down to the bare minimum of what happens in the "production" code - to the same effect.
The mentioned test cases I ran on my machine with openjdk 7, log4j 1.2.17, no commons-logging. I know our build servers run with a sun-jdk 6.

Comment: In your pom the version of commons-logging you are using is 1.0.4.v200706111724, and I couldn't find an artifact with that group and name anywhere in Maven Central, which is unexpected for such a well known library. Maybe the version you are using is dodgy. Try specifying your dependency that same as in the answer to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241487

Comment: Updated to the 1.1.1 commons-logging:commons-logging version to the same effect.

As long as there are no major changes in the code (specifically the class/field dependency found in Level/Priority and the static initializer in Log4JLogger), the issue will remain, no matter what subversions are used (according to my hypothesis :)).

Comment: I ran your tests and was consistently able to get deadlocks for `TestLoadingByClassForName `, but couldn't get any for the other two. I tried rerouting the commons-logging calls via slf4j instead (see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html, "1.3.2.2 Using SLF4J"), but that didn't affect the outcome of the tests at all. You never know though, it may still be worth a try in your actual project.

Comment: Yes, it is actually not that easy to get them. I was executing them on the command line in an endless loop eventually. But for the `TestMixedLoggerInstantiation` you need to fiddle with the sleep value a bit (needs roughly to be the execution time of the test -10ms), or else there won't be a deadlock at all. That is because commons-logging initially takes much longer to instantiate a Logger than log4j

Comment: I downloaded the code from GitHub but it does not hang. It pints, though, `log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (net.tcc.classloading.UseLog4JLogger).`. Please provide log4j configuration and detailed instructions to recreate the deadlock.

Comment: @Alexei Kaigorodov:
The missing log4j configuration is ok, I don't use one either. Log4j just sets up a default configuration; nevertheless, the configuration adds nothing to the deadlock scenario.
I've added a "Reproducing the deadlock" section to the original post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found the answer in the *Java Language Specification*, specifically in chapter [12.4.2 Detailed Initialization Procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2).
There it says

> [...]
> 2) If the Class object for C indicates that initialization is in progress for C by some other thread, then [...] ***block the current thread*** until informed that the in-progress initialization has completed, [...]
> 7) Next, if C is a class rather than an interface, and its superclass SC has not yet been initialized, then ***recursively perform this entire procedure for SC***
> 10) If the execution of the initializers completes normally, [...] label the Class object for C as fully initialized, ***notify all waiting threads***, [...]

So the behaviour observed is exactly as specified by the JLS. I'm still a bit baffled that there's no means to detect such a deadlock. And why the threads are marked as RUNNABLE - but I guess this isn't your typical bytecode to be executed, so who knows...

#### How to fix the issue

The solution for the problem was to get rid of `commons-logging`. As [@Robert Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1086631/robert-johnson) pointed out, this can *easily* be done by using `org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j` instead. I also checked the SLF code: it does not "take advantage" of the unlucky log4j design.

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis is correct.
You can try to run your concurrent tests in different classloaders, see the discussion [here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/issues/245) on how to do it. There's is an open bug in [Surefire](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-749) and discussion in [JUnit groups](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/junit/message/23485) on this issue. 
As a workaround you can use *org.apache.myfaces.test.runners.TestPerClassLoaderRunner* as described in the link above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd have expected a bit more details than merely agreeing to what I observed; specifically pointing out how class loading, static initialization etc. works.

Also thanks for poiting out the workarounds for my imminent problem!

Comment: Initialization of Classes and Interfaces from JLS:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/execution.html#12.4